# How to set placeholder value changeble

Tags: javascript, html

I Want placeholder value change by set interval but when i'm running my code nothing is happen.
Is there anyone who can help me.

`<form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail" name="e-mail" id="email"/>
</form>`

```
<script>
    var holder = setInterval(function(){
        var emailplaceholder = document.getElementById('email').placeholder;
        if (emailplaceholder == 'Enter E-mail') {
            document.getElementById('email').placeholder = 'yourmail@example.com';
            document.getElementById('email').placeholder = emailplaceholder;
        };
     },400); 
</script>
```

Comment: What's the goal, to have the placeholder text flash between the two strings?

Comment: yes, I wanna show two placeholder values. which should change 'Enter E-mail' to 'yourmail@example.com' and then 'yourmail@example.com' to 'Enter E-mail'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/WFU7PGNYMcUKK180cCt7

Its possible your script was running before the dom was created or not running at all depending on when you loaded it

```
<input type="email" placeholder="abc@gmail.com" id="email" />

(function(){
  var email = document.getElementById('email');

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    email.placeholder = email.placeholder === 'abc@gmail.com' ? 
        'Enter email' : 'abc@gmail.com';
  }, 1000);

  function clearInterval(){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the expected behaviour is, but your code is overriding the new placeholder value with the original placeholder value stored in the `emailplaceholder` variable.

If you want the *'yourmail@example.com'* value just remove the last line of code in the setinterval function.

e.g

```
<script>
    var holder = setInterval(function(){
        var emailplaceholder = document.getElementById('email').placeholder;
        if (emailplaceholder == 'Enter E-mail') {
            document.getElementById('email').placeholder = 'yourmail@example.com';
            // document.getElementById('email').placeholder = emailplaceholder;
        };
     },400); 
</script>
```

This will set the placeholder to be: **yourmail@example.com** after 400ms.

If you want something else to happen, please update your post to indicate the expected functionality.